# Jquery Conflict when use requirejs with jquery from google apis

Tags: requirejs, jquery

I have problem conflict when import more jquery files in on my project. The context in here is : i'm running a project without import requirejs, on this project i have already imported jquery and some jquery plugins on that, it works fine. And now, i need to use a service from the other site, it need to use requirejs to loading some javascript files from that site :

```
 prefixUrl = "http://mysite.com";

require = {
  baseUrl : prefixUrl + "/js",
  waitSeconds : 30,

  paths : {
    "jquery" : "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min",
    "jquery.validate" : "/jquery.validate.min-1.8.1",
    "jquery.string" : "/jQueryString-2.0.2-Min",
    "jquery.cookie" : "/jquery.cookie",
    "jquery.lightbox" : "/lightbox/jquery.lightbox",
    "thickbox" : "/thickbox/thickbox",
    "marketo.form" : "mktFormSupport",
    "templates" : "../templates",
    "login" : "/cloud-workspaces-extension/js/login",
    "rememberme-checkbox" : "/platform-extension/javascript/iphone-style-checkboxes"
  },

  shim : {
    'jquery.validate' : [ "jquery" ],
    'jquery.string' : [ "jquery" ],
    'jquery.cookie' : [ "jquery" ],
    'jquery.lightbox' : [ "jquery" ],
    "thickbox" : [ "jquery" ],
    "marketo.form" : {
      deps : [ "jquery" ],
      exports : "Mkto"
    },
    "rememberme-checkbox" : [ "jquery" ]
  },
  deps : [ "jquery", "jquery.validate", "jquery.string", "jquery.cookie" ].
  callback: function(){
    // handle
  }  
}
```

As you can see, it will be loading more a jquery file 1.7 from googleapis. That means it will overrite the current jquery on my project (i didn't use jquery noConflict) and some jquery plugins which init when the page load and document ready has been reset and remove instances their handles.

So, anybody can help me find another the solution for this case? I can use jquery noconflict for the current on my site, but that mean i will replace a lots of things javascript running good on my site. So, i'm looking for the good way can be import the service and workaround in it.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can't you just remove the scripts you've already loaded separately from the RequireJS config above? For instance, remove the entry for jQuery?

Comment: i can't remove the scripts loaded from the requirejs
I can change the instance jquery, but that mean i need to change in all the other scripts which init jquery plugins using on current site. I really don't want to do that :(
The problem on here is the jquery loaded on current and init plugins before the jquery from the requirejs loaded. So, the current jquery has been overrited. Example: when you call var obj = new Object() to reset instances from old one

Comment: anybody can help me to fix this issue?